# 401 Unauthorized error when calling rest service in salesforce from external tool

Tags: integration, rest-service

I am trying to call a rest service(works fine in workbench) from a external tool and I am getting the following error

> [{"message":"Session expired or
>   invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have written AUthorization as Oauth in your request header. Please make that **Bearer** as shown below

[image]

Comment: Same error with Bearer too..

Comment: have you generated access_token ?

Comment: verify with following steps http://sfdcbeginner.com/how-to-test-salesforce-rest-api.html

Comment: I dont get the error anymore but I am not able to successfully call the webservice. There is no POST happening at all.